# Kerberos: Wrong principal / realm for ssh-server login on a server in a subdomain

Tags: ssh, kerberos, single-sign-on

I currently try so setup the kerberos auth on a server living in a sub domain "sub.example.com". The KDC manages EXAMPLE.COM together with a dns server which manages 'example.com'. Due to organizational reasons we have a subdomain 'sub.example.com' for some servers (server1.sub.example.com). This subdomain is managed by a separate DNS server. There, the Kerberos login via pam works fine on this server using the following `/etc/krb5.conf` file:

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
        clockskew = 300
        ticket_lifetime = 2days
        renew_lifetime = 365days
        renewable = true
        forwardable = true

[realms]
        EXAMPLE.COM = {
                kdc = kerberos.example.com
        }
```

If I now connect with enabled Kerberos using kerberized ssh, I get

```
$ssh -vvv server1.sub.example.com
...
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server krbtgt/SUB.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server krbtgt/SUB.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug3: send packet: type 50
...
```

and return to password login. How can I convince kerberos/ssh to use `krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM` instead of `krbtgt/SUB.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM` for the servers inside the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try adding in /etc/krb5.conf:

```
[domain_realm]
 example.com  = EXAMPLE.COM
 .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Hmmm.  I thought sure that would work.  Maybe try:

```
[domain_realm]
  example.com  = EXAMPLE.COM
 .example.com  = EXAMPLE.COM
 sub.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
.sub.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Well, that's all I can think of to try.  Hopefully someone who knows more will come along.

Comment: I tried but this does not work. I already found this but it did not change the situation.

Comment: Your edit does not help at all an the problem stays the same.

Comment: You need to add these lines to krb5.conf on the ssh client system, not on the `server1.sub.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution that worked for me

I faced this problem too and this is how I solved it.

I created a `~/.k5identity` file following [this documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_config/k5identity.html) and containing just the 2 lines below:

```
myuser@SUB.EXAMPLE.COM    realm=SUB.EXAMPLE.COM
myuser@SUB.EXAMPLE.COM    host=*.sub.example.com
```

### Troubleshooting

As far as I can tell, this problem is caused by OpenSSH client's `ccselect` module using the wrong method to select a credentials cache for this authentication.

Without the above `~/.k5identity` file I would see this when troubleshooting the kerberos bits in the ssh command as below:

```
$ KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr ssh -Mvvvv server.sub.example.com uptime |& less

(...)
ccselect module hostname chose cache KCM:1003 with client principal myuser@EXAMPLE.COM for server principal host/server.sub.example.com@SUB.EXAMPLE.COM
(...)
```

Note that ssh's ccselect plugin automatically selects the existing credential from my credential cache, and it does so with the WRONG realm name. That's why ssh ends up asking about `Server krbtgt/SUB.EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM` instead of `Server krbtgt/SUB.EXAMPLE.COM@SUB.EXAMPLE.COM`.

With the above `~/.k5identity` this is what the kerberos-tracing ssh command shows:

```
(...)
ccselect module k5identity chose cache KCM:1003:77967 with client principal myuser@SUB.EXAMPLE.COM for server principal host/server.sub.example.com@SUB.EXAMPLE.COM
(...)
```

From then on, only the correct realm (SUB.EXAMPLE.COM) was attempted by ssh.